# How to automatically remove instances in EB whose status OutOfService is?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My current configuration provides that there must be minium 6 healthy instances. If there are no 6 healthy instances, an instance is added to it again 6 healthy are provided. The result is, that my LoadBalancer list 8 instance with 6 healty but 2 OutOfService. How can I terminate these two automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your elastic beanstalk configuration is set to use the ELB for health checking. If you do this, then the ASG will cycle instances that become out of service in the ELB.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html